# Is $(X,d)$ is complete? Yes/no

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given the metric space $(X,d)$ with $X := (0,\infty)$ and $d(x,y)=|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|$,

Is   $(X,d)$ is complete?

My attempt : N0 . Let $(x_n) $ be a Cauchy sequence then  $d(x_n, x_m)<\epsilon$ so $\mid \ln(x_n)-\ln(x_m)\mid \rightarrow 0.$ And $$d(x_n,x_m)=\mid \ln(x_n)-\ln(x_m)\mid=\mid \ln\frac{x_n}{x_m}\mid=0$$ So $\frac{x_n}{x_m} \rightarrow 1$ then subsequencec $(x_n)$ and $(x_m) $ have same limit and the sequence is convergent. But  $d(x_n, x_m) = 0  \notin  X$

So  $(X, d)$  is not complete

Is its true ?

Comment: $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ must be a sequence in $X$. Distance does not need to be in $X$. In fact, for abstract spaces it won't be

Comment: Write $x_n = e^{y_n}$, where $y_n \in \mathbb R$ Then $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ means $|\ln(e^{y_n}) - \ln(e^{y_m})| < \epsilon$, so $|y_n - y_m| < \epsilon$. Since $(\mathbb R,d_e)$, where $d_e(x,y) = |x-y|$ is complete, we have that sequence $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ has a limit $y \in \mathbb R$. By continuity of function $t \to e^t$, we get that also $x_n$ has a limit $x$ which is equal to $e^y$.

Comment: @DominikKutek thanks u

Comment: No problem, as I see, I forget to mention, but it is important, that $x=e^y \in X$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metric space is complete. One of the major mistakes that caught my attention was when you wrote

$$d(x_n,x_m)=\mid \ln(x_n)-\ln(x_m)\mid=\mid \ln\frac{x_n}{x_m}\mid=0$$

instead of writing

$$d(x_n,x_m)=\mid \ln(x_n)-\ln(x_m)\mid=\mid \ln\frac{x_n}{x_m}\mid<\epsilon$$

as $=0$ does not mean $<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the logical errors in your proof attempt, as noted in the answers by "Axion004" and "quid♦", I'd like to point out that your approach was flawed from the outset.

It appears you were trying to show that *every* Cauchy sequence fails to converge, but that could never work, since, for example, in *any* metric space, a constant sequence is *always* a Cauchy sequence, and *always* converges.

For a given metric space, to prove it is not complete, it suffices to find *one* Cauchy sequence which doesn't converge. But that plan would fail for the metric space $(X,d)$ in question since it is, in fact, complete.

To show that $(X,d)$ is complete, we can argue as follows . . .

Suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$.

Our goal is to show that $(x_n)$ converges in $(X,d)$.

Let $(y_n)$ be the sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $y_n = \log(x_n)$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $m,n\ge N$, we have $|\log(x_m)-\log(x_n)|<\epsilon$.

Equivalently, for all $m,n\ge N$, we have $|y_m-y_n|<\epsilon$.

Hence $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

But then since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, it follows that $(y_n)$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ to $r$ say.

Using limits in $\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=r\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(x_n)=r\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(x_n)=\log(e^r)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\lim_{n\to\infty}|\log(x_n)-\log(e^r)|=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,e^r)=0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Hence $(x_n)$ converges in $(X,d)$ to $e^r$.

It follows that $(X,d)$ is complete.

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with your approach.

First, you do not spell out exactly what it means to be a Cauchy sequence.

Second, you write

> $\mid \ln(x_n)-\ln(x_m)\mid \rightarrow 0$

but what is this supposed to mean exactly?

Third, you write

> then subsequence $(x_n)$ and $(x_m) $ have

But what subsequences are you talking about?

Fourth, you write

> But  $d(x_n, x_m) = 0  \notin  X$

Two problems with that. First, it is not clear what exactly you mean.
Yet more crucially it is not really relevant where the distance which "is" $0$ is in the space or not. To appreciate this consider the space $[3,5]$ with the usual metric. I assume you know that it is complete, but your argument might show that it is not complete.

Finally, the space is actually complete.